# Proving this function is not continuous at $0$ using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $$ g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1/x & x \neq 0 \\ y & x = 0 \end{cases}$$ is not continuous in $0$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt:** Fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$. We need to prove that $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}: |x| < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - f(0) | \geq \epsilon.$

I'm not sure how to pick my $x$ and $\epsilon$ here. I let $\epsilon = 1$. Let $\delta > 0$. Let $x = \delta/2$, so that $|x| < \delta$. Then $$| f(x) - f(0) | = | 1/x - y | = | 2 / \delta - y|. $$ I don't know how to get this bigger than the chosen $\epsilon$. Any help?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $c$, then it must be bounded above in some neighourhood of $c$, since for arbitrary $\epsilon$ we have $f(x) < f(c) + \epsilon$ in a neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your chouice of $x$ is not good, since, if $y=0$ and $\delta=3$, then $$|\frac2\delta-y|=|\frac23|=\frac23$$

which is **not** greater than $1$.

---

Your choice of $\epsilon$ is good, now I recommend you re-think your choice of $x$. Remember to draw the graph of $\frac1x$, and think about why $\frac 1x$ must be far from any value of $y$ for small values of $x$.

For example, to avoid the mistake you made before, you should make $x$ dependent on both $y$ and $\delta$, and somehow make sure that $x$ is **small** even if $\delta$ is not!

**Hint**:

It's easiest to find an $x>$ such that $\frac1x$ is **much bigger** than $y$.

**Hint 2**:

If $y$ is positive, then think about the number $\frac1y$...

Comment: I don't know. If I make $x$ dependent on both $y$ and $\delta$,then how can I be sure that the condition $|x| < \delta$ is satisfied?

Comment: @Kamil You can satisfy that condition because $x$ is dependent on $\delta$. For example, if you set $x=\frac12\cdot\min\{|y|, |\delta|\}$ (this is not the correct answer, it's just an example), then the condition is obviously satisfied.

Comment: I still don't see it. Thank you for trying to help, but your hints don't really help me. I'll try it again this evening.

Comment: The second hint is pretty big. Think about it

Comment: I think I found it. Suppose $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ (the other case is similar). Let $\epsilon = 1$. Let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. Pick $0 < x < \min\left\{\delta, \frac{1}{1+y}\right\}$. Then $|x| < \delta$ and $\frac{1}{x} > 1 + y$. Hence we have $|f(x) - y| = | \frac{1}{x} - y| > | 1 + y - y| \geq 1$. Q.E.D.

Comment: @Kamil Well done! Almost there! However $\frac1x>1+y$ is *not* true, since, if $x=\frac{1}{1+y}$, then $\frac1x$ is not greater than $1+y$, it's just greater than equal. Also, I would add a line or two more about why $\frac1x>1+y$ if $x=\delta$. But I see you get the idea.

Comment: @Kamil I hope you understand now why I didn't give you a full solution right away. I believe you learn more by actually doing the exercise, and I hope my hints helped with that!

Answer (score 1):

Case ($1$): when for  $x>0$ which satisfies: $f(x) > f(0)$. [1]

Our goal is to show:
 $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}: x < \delta \Rightarrow  f(x) - f(0)  \geq \epsilon$.

Notice that: for $\delta > 0$
which satisfies following condition: $x < \delta $

$$ \iff f(x) - f(0) = 1/x-y \geq 1/\delta - y $$

Since $\inf (f(x) - f(0)) = 1/\delta - y $ denote it as $M$.

Then for $x<\delta/2$ In the same way $f(x) -f(0) \geq 2/\delta - y$ Therefore, $\inf(f(x) -f(0)) =  2/\delta - y$ designate it as N.

And in these two condition, use M and N as $\epsilon$ and the prove is done. (Because there is no absolute operation, it is clear to see that $M<N$.

Case (2): when for  $x<0$ which satisfies: $f(x) < f(0)$. The proof is almost same except that some inequality changes.

Case (3): when for $x>0$ which satisfies $f(x) \leq f(0)$. By the monotony of $1/x$, it is easy to show this case is equivalent to Case(1).

Case (4): when for $x<0$ which satisfies $f(x) \geq f(0)$. By the monotony of $1/x$, it is easy to show this case is equivalent to Case(2).

Here is why the inequality$[1]$ holds by contradiction, forall $x > 0$, $f(x)<f(0) \iff \sup 1/x < y $ let $u >0$ satisfying $ \sup 1/u < y$ Then $u/2 > 0$ But $2/u < y$. which means u is not a supermum of $1/x$. Contradiction.

EDIT:

In the case [1], there is an redundant confusing proof to show that $x<\delta/2$ the $\epsilon = N$. It is not necessary because $x<\delta$ the quantifier for $\delta$ is "forall" rather than "existence".

By the monotony of $1/x$, it can sow that $f(x)>f(0)$ for $x>0$ the x value's range must in $(0,\delta_0)$. Therefore, it should be declared as "for all $ \delta < 1/y$". Now it is more evident.

Comment: Are you saying we should pick $\epsilon = 1/\delta - y$ for case $1$? How can we pick $\epsilon$ in function of $\delta$, when $\delta$ is picked after $\epsilon$?

Comment: let $ϵ =1/\delta - y$. I think that my logic is a bit of problematic because I don't know why I should do some redundant proof on $x<\delta / 2$. I will try to fix it.